# Customized moreNavigationController resets after rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I use an UITabBarController which has more than 5 items. I customized moreNavigationController to remove navigation bar and making it dark. But when I rotate the device to landscape and come to the portrait again it shows the navigation bar at the top and its white again. This only happens when I select a ViewController from moreNavigationController and rotate it.

Here is my code :

```
class CustomTabBar: UITabBarController,UITabBarControllerDelegate {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    delegate = self
    self.customizableViewControllers = []
    self.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = true
}

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    // style all the tab bar windows and the More tab bar tableview
    if viewController == moreNavigationController,
        let moreTableView = moreNavigationController.topViewController?.view as? UITableView {
        moreNavigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        let dark = UIColor(hexString: "#1F242A")
       moreTableView.backgroundColor = dark
        moreTableView.tintColor = .white
        moreTableView.visibleCells.forEach{ cell in
            cell.backgroundColor = dark
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was achieved to do so using the code below. I used viewWillTransition before but the key part is running customization code **after** the transition.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { _ in
        self.moreNavigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }
}
```